# Can I use call higher exception blocks from an exception block?

Tags: python

Let's say I have a code that looks like this:

```
try:
    raise ValueError()
except ValueError as err:
    print("ValueError block")
    raise
except Exception as err:
    print("Exception block")
```

This prints:

```
ValueError block
```

and raises an exception. I want it to just print:

```
ValueError block
Exception block
```

Can I achieve that by somehow calling the Exception block from the ValueError block?

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions): "*A try statement may have more than one except clause, to specify handlers for different exceptions. __At most one handler will be executed__*". So your current layout will not work. Maybe a more sophisticated approach is possible

Comment: Also the next sentence: "Handlers only handle exceptions that occur in the corresponding try clause, not in other handlers of the same try statement."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to obey the rules of exception handling. In this case, you can use a nested `try` block:

```
try:
    try:
        raise ValueError()
    except ValueError as err:
        print("ValueError block")
        raise
except Exception as err:
    print("Exception block")
```

Comment: wow, that was both the best answer and an extremely easy way to get some votes.  you, what, added one `try:` and moved the indentations around a bit.  perfect.

Comment: @JLPeyret. Yup `try:` + 20 spaces is 25 total characters if you count the newline. All in all, a good days work.

Answer (score 0):

Since `ValueError` is a subclass of `Exception`, you could write one `except` block and check with `isinstance`:

```py
try:
    raise ValueError()

except Exception as err:
    if isinstance(err, ValueError):
        print("ValueError block")

    print("Exception block")
```